# NSTextView autocomplete and tags transforming

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nstextfield

How can I make NSTextField to support tags like Stackoverflow text field or Mac OS mail address autocompletion? I know that autocompletion for text field can be realized by standard instruments but how can I transform completed tag to "box" like Mail or StackOverflow's text field?

I can't understand what instruments I need to use to achieve such functionality.

[image: Stackoverflow's tags]

[image: Mail's tags]

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want to add to the text field it should be a view, you can check the **Using Overlay Views in Text Fields** inside the following article from Text Programming Guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/ManageTextFieldTextViews/ManageTextFieldTextViews.html